# Hadoop: Find 10 Most Frequent Words

Tags: python, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and python and I am trying to find the 10 most frequent words in a text. I have a file in the following format

```
Count1      Word1
Count2      Word2
```

what I am trying to do is to sort the counts in descending order then my reducer will output the top 10 lines. my mapper doesn't do anything, the data is sorted using this option

```
-jobconf mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options=-k1,1nr
```

and here is my reducer code

```
i=0

for line in sys.stdin:
    if(i==10):
            break
    print(line)
    i+=1
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: what is the problem what output did you get what module you are using provide those informations

Comment: The mapper should at least print the line back out. It can't do nothing. Also, this problem is a bit backwards from a standard top-N MapReduce because it's usually top values, not keys. So, assuming your keys are sorted in descending order (which is not the default sorting), then your reducer code at least looks good.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your answer. I managed to fix it but I still don't know why the original code doesn't work. I just replaced 'break' with 'continue' and it solved the problem. what I meant by "my mapper doesn't do anything" is that it just prints out the line back